# How to tell a chocolatey shim to use the path from original network location where the install file is located

Tags: chocolatey, shim

When installing a locally hosted chocolatey package based on an installer located on the local network I can see a shim is created. This shim I understand points to the original installer. But for this to work the shim needs to be run in the network location so that the installer can find other required files. I have tried to add the network location to the path using:
`Install-ChocolateyPath`
But I have not had success. 
I've also tried to create a Setup.exe.ignore file in the same directory as the original file on the network without success. 
I've seen references to `--shimgen-usetargetworkingdirectory` but I can't figure out how to implement it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out on my own and thought I would share. In `chocolateyinstall.ps1` I used `Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage` instead of `Install-ChocolateyPackage` which solved my issue related to paths and running the shim in the same directory as the original install file.

More info here:

https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-package

https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-install-package

comments in `chocolateyinstall.ps1` say it all.

```
## If you are making your own internal packages (organizations), you can embed the installer or 
## put on internal file share and use the following instead (you'll need to add $file to the above)
Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage @packageArgs # https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-install-package
```